# Is it possible to reference a measure in Dax without table Prefix?

Tags: dax

I am creating measures in a tabular model using DAX. I know that you can't create two  measures with the same name.

My question is: when calling a measure in the model using Dax do you have to state the table prefix where the measure was created (like  `Sales[MeasureName]`) or is it sufficient to use only the measure's name  `[MeasureName]`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to use the table prefix. The only time a table prefix is required is when making a column reference as an argument to a DAX function which is not scoped to the current table (SUMX's first argument, for example.)

Comment: In general, best practice is to always use fully qualified column names and measure names without table references. This is standard practice in code samples you will find, and helps a lot in mentally parsing complex measure definitions and queries.